# asp.net mvc learn from what host the resource has been requested

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to learn from what host the resource, for example js a file has been requested?

Example

**site.com -> request from mySite.com/api.js**

I so understand, I should use RouteConstraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {




        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
            {
                if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.EndsWith("api.js"))
                {
                    _dataManager.ApiCalls.Add(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), Request.UserHostAddress, Request.UserHostName);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```